# Mediapipe Webcam code showing Unknown C++ exception from Opencv code

Tags: python, c++, opencv, mediapipe

We are trying to execute below mediapipe code for webcam feed it was not running showing below error. Also webcam was showing black and white with clumsy pictures.

**Code:**

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Raw Webcam Feed', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have installed latest versions of mediapipe and opencv. There was no issues with webcam tried with tried with other applications. Can someone suggest on this.

**Error:
Unknown C++ exception from Opencv code**

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1J3D.png --- Error Image
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzJ1J.png --- Code Image

Comment: PLease share the error and other snippet exactly instead of their pics

Comment: and work on a minimal reproducible example. that means, if the error can be reproduced without mediapipe, remove mediapipe from the question (and code).

Comment: are you using windows? can you check if `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)` is solving your issue?

Comment: @RoyAmoial Thanks a lot ... after adding this code issue got resolved.

Comment: @Raaa Glad to hear! I added the answer, if you can upvote for it more people will be able to see and use answer for the future. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Following my answer that helped in the comments:

***Solution***

Sometimes there are some issues with the OpenCV video capturing for USB webcam in Windows. Some webcams are handled exclusively from DirectShow(or outdated VFW). You can read more about it [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html).

this should solve your problem:

change `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` to `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)`.